# Create Generic List derrived form Observable Collection

Tags: c#

I want to build an `ObservableCollection` that derrives from the basic `ObservableCollection`, in order to do certain things depending on the type of the children the Collection contains.

```
public class DbListBase : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public DbListBase()
    {
        if (TypeOf(T) == Machine) {Do This}

        if (TypeOf(T) == Person) {Do That}
    }
}
```

However, the `<T>` is underlined with the errormessage Type or Namespace T not found.

I've tried to go around it, by using a base class, which all other classes inherit, like this.

```
public class DbListBase : ObservableCollection<ModelBase>
{
    public DbListBase()
    {
        // How would I check for the Type of child?
    }
}
```

But creating an instance of `DbListBase` won't let me do this:

```
DbListBase MachineList = new DbListBase<Machine>();
```

How can I make the first approach `DbListBase : ObservableCollection<T>` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate reason for your error is: your class must be generic, too:

```
public class DbListBase<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
               // here ^^^^
```

But I don't like the idea of a **generic** type that does different things *depending* on the generic argument. *Generic* should be type-*independent*.

So I'd suggest to make different derivates for each type you need it for:

```
public class DbListBaseForType1 : ObservableCollection<Type1> // Type1 as generic argument for the base class
{
    // special behaviour for Type1
}

public class DbListBaseForType2 : ObservableCollection<Type2> // Type2 as generic argument for the base class
{
    // special behaviour for Type1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. The idea is to fill the collection with objects that contain values from a database. Depending on the type of object I would have to access different databasevieww.